# Programatically populate field_4 after choosing values from other fields?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, sql

I'm working with QGis 2.8, editing the attribute table of a SHP file, named  "myTable".
I need to populate field_4 with the conditions listed below:

---

```
For 1 to n (it runs across records of myTable)                                              
  select record n                                   
    set var1 = field_1.value (it puts the value of field_1 in var1) 
      if field_2 >1 then field_4.value = 'OK'                   
      else                              
      SELECT MAX(field_2) FROM myTable WHERE field_1.value = var1 (it selects the record with the higher value of those who have field_1=var1)
      set var3 = field_3.value (it copies field_3 value into var3)                  
      end                               
    select record n (it come's back to current record)                              
    set field_4.value = var3 (it populates field_4 with var3 value)                 
next n
```

---

myTable will be like this after running:

geometry, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4

```
1       1       10          a       ok
2       1       1           b       c
3       1       80          c       ok
4       2       60          d       ok
5       2       20          e       ok
6       2       1           f       d
7       2       5           g       ok
8       1       1           h       c
9       1       8           i       ok
10      2       5           l       ok
11      2       5           m       ok
12      2       4           n       ok
13      3       39          o       ok
14      3       1           p       r
15      3       10          q       ok
16      3       50          r       ok
```

I'd like write this script in Python, but my skill is very low !!
(note that it calls some SQL functions)
I don't know how to use "cursor" tecnique into Python.
Can someone help me writing this procedure?